# don't stop service when application stopped

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Actually i'm developing an android application that should get notifications from server every minute and for ever, so i'm using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver, IntentService, AlarmManager` and this is my code:

```
    public class SampleAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private static final long PERIOD = 3000;
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        Intent service = new Intent(context, SampleSchedulingService.class);

        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000, PERIOD, alarmIntent);
        Log.i("SampleAlarmReceiver ", "SampleAlarmReceiver " + new Date().toString());
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);           
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
        if (alarmMgr!= null) {
            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        }

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, SampleBootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

this my service code:

```
    public class SampleSchedulingService extends IntentService {
    public SampleSchedulingService() {
        super("SchedulingService");
    }

    public static final String TAG = "Scheduling Demo";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1; 
    public static final String SEARCH_STRING = "doodle";
    public static final String URL = "http://www.google.com";
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String urlString = URL;

        String result ="";

        // Try to connect to the Google homepage and download content.
        try {
            result = loadFromNetwork(urlString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, getString(R.string.connection_error));
        }

        if (result.indexOf(SEARCH_STRING) != -1) {
            sendNotification(getString(R.string.doodle_found));
            Log.i(TAG, "Found doodle!!");
        } else {
            sendNotification(getString(R.string.no_doodle));
            Log.i(TAG, "No doodle found. :-(");
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the BroadcastReceiver.
        SampleAlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        // END_INCLUDE(service_onhandle)
    }

    // Post a notification indicating whether a doodle was found.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
               this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.doodle_alert))
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

    private String loadFromNetwork(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        String str ="";

        try {
            stream = downloadUrl(urlString);
            str = readIt(stream);
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }      
        }
        return str;
    }

    private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Start the query
        conn.connect();
        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
        return stream;
    }

    private String readIt(InputStream stream) throws IOException {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        for(String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) 
            builder.append(line);
        reader.close();
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

My problem is: the service stopped when i exit the application, how can fixe it let the service alive for ever. (like facebook Notification)

Comment: The service stops when `onHandleIntent()` ends. That is the point behind an `IntentService`.

Comment: IntenetService stops the service after all start requests have been handled, so you never have to call stopSelf(). If you do not want to stop your service then use service public class SampleSchedulingService extends Service.